# What is the Kafka equivalent of RabbitMQ's exchanges?

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-kafka

I come from a RabbitMQ background, and with RabbitMQ, you can set up exchanges that route messages to different queues based on a routing key.

In Kafka, how I am currently understanding topics is that they can be thought of as queues (that never get emptied). However, I am interested in putting different messages into different topics based on a certain criteria, and I would like to avoid doing that logic on the producer side.

Are there Kafka equivalent(s) to RabbitMQ's exchanges?

Answer (score 8):

There is no equivalent. The only way to route different messages to 
different topics is to put that logic on the producer side. Even deciding which partition of a topic to send an individual message to is left up to the producer.

Kafka's great strength is that it's really simple. That's part of why Kafka can scale really, really well. The downside is that Kafka doesn't have the feature set of a conventional message queue.

Answer (score -1):

Kafka has something called a message key and when a message key added to the message for the first time Kafka pushes it to a random partition in the topic but when there is a new message with the same message key then Kafka pushes it to the same partition

Comment: Yes, you can control with such key that messages with the same key will be in the same Partition of the Topic. But that's not what was asked. In this case you are still in the same Topic(Queue). It make sense only when you want to be sure that messages with certain key will be pushed to the same partiotion which means lineary pushed they lineary consumed with the same order, awoiding consumption order changes with parallel consumption from different partitions